# Pandas Split Columns in Columns different sizes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tabula

[image: Pandas_DataFrame]
--Edited--['SOLVED']

I am using tabula to convert pdf invoices to pandas dataframe, but the last column isn't in the good way.
I want to split the last row named 'PVF c/ IVA PVA s/Tx Desc% Tx Inf. IVA% P.Unit. Total Liq.'
I want to split, in each space, and have new columns ['PVFc/IVA', 'PVAs/Tx', 'Desc%' 'TxInf.', 'IVA%', 'P.Unit.', 'Total Liq.'], and the rows should be split for each space. Row2 '7,41', '6,30', '65,0', '0,03', '6', '2,24', '22,40'.

I have searched and found how to split, but... some rows will be split in 7 columns and other only in 6 columns and I get an error.

For more information, every row which 'PVP c/Iva' is NaN or 'Esc.' is 'NETT' don't have 'PVFc/IVA' value, so the (len) of the column is 6. it's possible for my analyses insert 0,00 as prefix in that rows to all have a 7 columns len().

Any solution is welcome, I am starting with Python and pandas... thanks for your time

I apply parts of the code from @Ahmed Sayed, and i have made progess,
to concatenate Nan Colums with other, first i replace Nan with a space

```
dataframe['placeHolderColumn'] = dataframe['placeHolderColumn'].fillna(value='')
```

after some trying e errors, i found that sometimes there are more than one space, so I have replaced all spaces for one space, and then replace '*'

```
dataframe["newColumn"]= dataframe['newColumn'].str.replace('  ','*')
```

the i have created a new column to confirme the split element

```
dataframe["count2"]= dataframe['newColumn'].str.count('\*', re.I)
```

I get this result

[image: Image after transformations]

So, as last job i apply the split métode,

```
dataframe[['c1','c2','c3','c4','c5','c6']] = dataframe['newColumn'].str.split('*', expand=True)
```

but i get this error

[image: Last error]

--FOUND--
i have to pass another column name, i am just passing 6 new colums and i have 7 values

`dataframe[['c1','c2','c3','c4','c5','c6', 'c7']] = dataframe['newColumn'].str.split('*', expand=True)`

Answer (score 0):

So the problem here is the cells do not have an equal number of values in that column, we can address this by counting the number of values and wherever we see a missing value, we can add a dummy 00 at the beginning so it is easier for us to split later.

first, let's create a column with the number of spaces. This gives the number of values in that row.

```
import re
df["count"]= df['PVF c/ IVA PVA s/Tx Desc% Tx Inf. IVA% P.Unit. Total Liq.'].str.count(' ', re.I)
```

then, if the count is less than what we are expecting, let's append a zero at the beginning of each cell string

```
# here we compare the number of spaces to 5, 5 is for the short cells that need a dummy 00 at the beginning
df.loc[df["count"] <= 5, 'placeHolderColumn'] = '00 '  #notice there is a space after the zeros
# now let's create a new column and merge the placeHolderColumn column to the old values column
df['newColumn'] = df['placeHolderColumn'] + df['PVF c/ IVA PVA s/Tx Desc% Tx Inf. IVA% P.Unit. Total Liq.'].astype(str)
```

lastly, we can split the column by

```
df[['c1','c2','c3','c4','c5','c6']] = df['newColumn'].str.split(' ', expand=True)
```

Comment: I already try , but i get an error because they don´t all have the same len, as i sayed, for example row index 5 will generate 6 colums and row index 2 will generate 7 colums

Comment: i have updated my answer. the idea is to create another column with the count of spaces, spaces here represent the values in the column. then create a fictitious column to hold '00 ' if the count is less than what we expect. 
then, merge the two columns together before splitting

Comment: Thanks for the update, i have tryed but there are some bugs... df.loc[df["count"] <= 5, 'placeHolderColumn'] = '00 ', -> here have to be <=7, there are 7 ou 8 spaces. but, great help. in his line df['newColumn'] = df['placeHolderColumn'] + df['PVF c/ IVA PVA s/Tx Desc% Tx Inf. IVA% P.Unit. Total Liq.'].astype(str) -> i think it should have a concatenate of the to colums, but if the row in placeHolderColumn is Nan, the new column is also Nan, and if placeHolderColumn is '00 ' the newcolum is correct, it's not concatenating if Nan in row